# Java WebApp and Managed Identity

Tags: java, azure-eventhub, azure-managed-identity

anybody can help me to understand if there is any way to use ***Managed Identity*** (internal a ***Java Web App***) to connect to Event Hub using ***Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs (legacy)*** library?

The customer is not able to migrate to *Azure.Messaging.EventHubs (latest)* yet and he is challenging me to understand if he can still use the legacy one.

Thanks
Ric

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the sample here https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs/tree/master/samples/Java/Rbac ? It covers Managed Identity in the ReadMe which requires slight code change.

Comment: This is working for VMs but it failing for Java WebApp.

Comment: Thanks the customer is happy with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is possible via the connection string.  The [`ConnectionStringBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.connectionstringbuilder) provides a [`setAuthentication`](https://learn.microsoft.com/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.connectionstringbuilder.setauthentication).  Passing the argument "Managed Identity" should result in a connection string configured to use the managed identity, assuming the host supports it.

Comment: Do you think is working for Java WebApp (not inside a VM)?

Comment: Is your host environment implementing the Managed Identity endpoint in the same manner as a VM is?  There are assumptions made about the host environment following the same structure as an Azure host environment with a managed identity.   If not, you don't want "managed identity",  you'll likely be best served by using a token provider for your auth.